# Scraping titles and metatags from millions of urls

Tags: java, python, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have seen plenty of tools so far, as Scrapy or Selenium. Basically the question is not on how to scrape a website, but how to scrape millions of website in a decent amount of time, while respecting robots.txt and internet politeness.

I have collected over a billion of urls so far, but now I need to scrape each of them in order to fetch "title" and "metatags".

Is this possible? And how? Which tool would allow me to scrape several urls without being blocked or banned from a website?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, asking for a tool on SO is considered to be *off-topic* question and should be closed

Comment: I misused a word in English. I meant more tool as a code snippet. Since a normal iteration would get me blocked from any website. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

So here I am providing a comprehensive solution. Using the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests) and [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/bs4) libs would be the best solution for you.

So first of all you have *a billion URLs* as a list I assume. Your target is to get the `title` and the `meta`content from those sites.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://github.com', 'http://bitbucket.com', ...] # upto 1 billion urls :o
# looping through the billion URLs 
for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url).text # making the request
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html5lib') 
    meta_content = soup.findAll('meta', content=True) # here you get your meta tag contents
    title_content = soup.findAll('title') # here you get your title tag contents
    print ("Meta for %s: %s" % (url, meta_content))
    print ("Title for %s: %s" % (url, title_content))
```

**Note:** `html.parser` doesn't parse `<meta>` tags properly. It doesn't realize they're self-closing, hence I used the `html5lib` library.